# SugarORM remove log.i

Tags: android, sugarorm

how can I remove

```
        Log.i("Sugar", this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " saved : " + this.id);
```

on line 150 in SugarRecord.class?

I'm inserting data very frequently and it would be nicer if it didn't log.

Answer (score 2):

In the meta-data tag in the manifest file

```
<application
       .... >
  <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="false" />`
```

Comment: This does not disable the logging of "saved" info lines.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing sugar from gradle, you'll probably have to add and build the project from source to your project.

Then you can just comment it out.  I haven't found any other way to disable this specific log message, and I'm not sure why it isn't included with the other logging message when disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `SugarRecord.class` is using the `android.util.Log` class in the above line. Which means it may not be configurable through methods or a configuration setting, You may have to include the source rather than as a dependency and remove it from your source code or build a configuration flags which allow logging only when they are set.